# How to convert epoch to timestamp in NiFi within a JSON file?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I'm having issues with getting an epoch conversion to Timestamp to work properly. So far my example timestamp looks like the following:

```json
{"createTime": 1510932843000}
```

What my end goal is to make it look like the following:

```
2017-11-17 3:34:03.000
```

The things I've tried so far are the `UpdateRecord` and `JoltTransformation` Processor. For the `UpdateRecord` I have tried various ways but all end in an error. The current code I have for this is:

```json
${field.value:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
JSON Object due to java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-11-17 15:34:03.000": For input string: "2017-11-17 15:34:03.000"
```

I have also tried the code without the `multiply(1000)` to the same effect.

I have also tried a `Jolt Transformation` of the following code:

```json
{
  "createTime": "${createTime:append('000'):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}"
}
```

This however results in the following:

```
"createTime": "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000"
```

Which isn't what I'm looking for as its the incorrect date result. Am I doing something wrong within my code itself or is another factor occurring? I've been working with this and searching all over for different kind of results and have tried multiple different formats with no success. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException means that you are trying to assign string (btw with with correctly formatted date) into a number field.

Comment: Ah okay, is there a way to update the Schema of it to change to `Date` from `Long` within the same processor? Just trying to find the best way for this to replicate if needed for other pipelines, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My preferred solution:

Use a **ScriptedTransformRecord** processor:

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```java
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.ZoneId;

def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Bratislava"))

record.setValue("createTimeFormatted", formatter.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(record.getAsLong("createTime"))))
return record
```

Output json:

```json
{
  "createTime" : 1510932843000,
  "createTimeFormatted" : "2017-11-17 16:34:03.000"
}
```

#### Another approach

Use 2 processors: **JoltTransformJSON** (convert type from Long to String) -> **UpdateRecord** (convert date).

**JoltTransformJSON** processor:

- `Jolt Transformation DSL`: `Chain`
- `Jolt specification`:

```json
[
 {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "createTime": "=toString"
    }
  }
]
```

**UpdateRecord** processor:

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Replacement Value Strategy`: `Literal Value`
- `/createTime` (dynamic property): `${field.value:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}`

Output json:

```json
{
  "createTime" : "2017-11-17 16:34:03.000"
}
```

Comment: I believe this would work in NiFi environment for the purposes. But however, for my work environment the `ScriptedTransformRecord` is under restricted access unfortunately. Is there another way of doing this outside of the `ScriptedTransformRecord`?

Comment: @Maykid I updated the answer with another approach without `ScriptedTransformRecord` processor

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for updating really appreciate it!!